# Good way to store phone numbers in django models

Tags: django, django-models

I was creating a model, and one of the fields is for a phone number. What exactly would be the best way to hold a phone number in a django model?

What would allow for the best functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this package https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field just install it with pip

Comment: thank you, did you create this? I also got this error:
Downloading/unpacking django-phonenumber-field
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-phonenumber-field (from versions: 0.2a1, 0.2a3)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for django-phonenumber-field
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/nir/Library/Logs/pip.log