# Integrating Phone number app in django

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in python. I am trying to integrate phonenumber app which I installed from the following url

https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field

Reference url is [Good way to store phone numbers in django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126124/good-way-to-store-phone-numbers-in-django-models)

I have added `'phonenumber_field'` in installed apps in settings.py.

`forms.py` code looks like this

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Div, Field
from ajax_select.fields import AutoCompleteSelectField, AutoCompleteField
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from . import models

class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
```

Signup html

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% load i18n crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Signup" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{% trans "Sign Up" %}</h1>

<p>{% blocktrans %}Already have an account? Then please <a href="{{ login_url }}">sign in</a>.{% endblocktrans %}</p>

<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

But in my signup form there is no phone field showing.Is it that I have to call the function inside the model instead in forms.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: please, show your html template

Comment: @BearBrown I have edited the post with the signup.html code.

Comment: You should also update your question to include the fact that you're using "crispy" for form rendering.

Comment: can you try replace `{{ form|crispy }}` on `{{ form.as_p }}` just look on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're importing the model field, not the form field.

```
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
```

The model field is meant to go in your model, not for your form.

```
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class SignupModel:
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
```

You could then use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/) to generate a form with all the same fields as your model.

However, if you insist on manually building your form, you need to import the form field instead.

```
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField

class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
```

Comment: Brilliant. It worked. The way you have explained is awesome. I don't why I always understand better in SO than going through the official documentation.